# Outputting special characters in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, css

Here's the code that my view uses to diplay the first name of the user. I want to add *'s* to the name

```
<h3 class="cabin-sketch"><%= @user.first_name + "Ribbit Profile" %>
```

Also here's the code to an username and I wish add a @ before the username. How can I achieve both of this in rails. Additionally is there any helper method in Rails 4 that let's me capitalize the first alphabet of the first name and the last name?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the chars into your string, nothing is specail.

```
<h3 class="cabin-sketch"><%= "@#{@user.first_name}'s Recrea8 Profile" %>
```

Comment: Please see the last part. Is there a helper to pluralize the first alphabet?

Comment: try `titleize`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-titleize